# laravel cannot use url correctly

Tags: php, laravel, url

I just install laravel environment, I got some problem with url, I do not understand about it. here it index.php that run on first.

```
<a href="pass">pass to page</a>
```

when I click the pass to page link it maybe go to page that I link to. but it was 404 not found . 
here is routes.php in app directory

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('pass', 'PassController@passToPage');
```

and here is function in PassController

```
public function passToPage()
{
    return View::make('pass');
}
```

I note that I use only '\'(default directory), I cannot use other directory.
thank in advance I am in new laravel.

Comment: if you go to http://localhost/test/ccc/public/pass does that work?

Comment: it not work. it know only ccc/public/ only

Comment: what if you put a forward slash in front of pass (e.g `Route::get('/pass', 'PassController@passToPage');`)

Comment: it not work, I try a lot of way

Answer (score 0):

You have tricky part in your code.

First you should use slash prefix in your links. For example:

```
<a href="/pass">pass to page</a>
```

or like this

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('pass', $params) }}">
```

If you use it without slash the href value could be prepend to current route. If you use it with slash prefix it will alway points to root endpoint.

You can consider usig named routes. For example

```
Route::get('pass', [
    'as' => 'pass', 'uses' => 'PassController@passToPage'
]);
```

and then call this route in your blade view like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('pass', $params) }}">
```

> $params could be replaced with [] if the is none params

If the error still ocures the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I have a question, I cannot access this url http://localhost/test/ccc/public/pass    ... is it problem?

Comment: Does your other routes work properly? If you want to acces this route you should put the href value to  <a href="/test/ccc/public/pass">pass to page</a> and in routesRoute::get('/test/ccc/public/pass', 'PassController@passToPage');

Comment: no no, I meant that I directory in this url but it not work . but when I try 'localhost/test/ccc/public/index.php/pass' it work with this directory. but I don't want exist with index.php

Comment: Looks like you are doing something unusual here. I think your problem is in your dev environment configuration. I have insufficient information to help you out here.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to used **named routes**. This way you can change the URL without modifying the links in your application.

```
Route::get('pass', ['uses' => 'PassController@passToPage', 'as' => 'pass']);

<a href="{{ route('pass') }}">pass to page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this problem. first time I try direct to this url

```
http://localhost/test/ccc/public/pass
```

it's not work, but when I want to go to page page I need to include index.php as like this

```
http://localhost/test/ccc/public/index.php/pass
```

when I type this, it work but I want to remove index.php from url .
to solve this problem I need to enable mod_rewrite. so I got to httpd.conf, and remove # sign and enable mod_rewrite. now it work with this url

```
http://localhost/test/ccc/public/pass
```